# Remove HTML from the body of the text file

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am currently writing a function to get the review and rating of an album by getting it from Pitchfork and removing HTML. The result should be a list with 2 elements: the review and the score of that album.
So far I have this and I am still figuring out what to return, the regex of the HTML part and the `paste0` function. Thank you for your time!

```
pitchfork = function(url){
  save = getURL(url)
  cat(save,file = "review.txt")
  a1 = '<div class="contents dropcap"><p>'
  b1 = str_replace(save, paste0("^.*",a1),"")
  a2 = '</div><a class="end-mark-container" href="/">'
  b2 = str_replace(b1, paste0(a2,".*$"),"")
}
```

Comment: It's usually a [bad idea to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). Why not use `rvest` and/or `xml2`/`XML` to parse HTML?

Comment: here is the URL: https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene/
and the expected output should be a list with 2 elements: the review (text) and the rating (numeric)

Comment: I'll try that. My function is deleting everything from the beginning to the string `a1` and everything from `a2` til the end, leave the body of the text left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene"
html <- read_html(url)

review <- html %>%
    xml_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    enframe("paragraph_no", "text")
review
## A tibble: 14 x 2
#   paragraph_no text
#          <int> <chr>
# 1            1 Best new music
# 2            2 Grimes’ first project as a bona fide pop star is more morose th…
# 3            3 In 2011, Grimes was eager to say in an interview that she had “…
# 4            4 Miss Anthropocene is Grimes’ fifth album and her first as that …
# 5            5 The result is a record that’s more morose than her previous wor…
# 6            6 In November 2018, Grimes released “We Appreciate Power,” a coll…
# 7            7 When Grimes veers away from high concept toward examining intim…
# 8            8 Miss Anthropocene thrills when it reveals a refined, linear evo…
# 9            9 So much about the actual music of Miss Anthropocene succeeds th…
#10           10 And that’s the obstacle, the slimy mouthfeel, standing in the w…
#11           11 Correction: An earlier version of this review erroneously state…
#12           12 Listen to our Best New Music playlist on Spotify and Apple Musi…
#13           13 Buy: Rough Trade
#14           14 (Pitchfork may earn a commission from purchases made through af…
```

`review` is a `tibble` and contains the review split by paragraph; it might need some additional cleaning up (like removing the first and last row(s)).

For the score we can use a class attribute selector

```
score <- html %>% xml_nodes("[class='score']") %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()
score
#[1] 8.2
```

---

### Wrapping things up (in a function)

Let's wrap everything in a `function` that returns a `list` with the review `tibble` and numeric score.

```
get_pitchfork_data <- function(url) {
    html <- read_html(url)
    list(
        review = html %>%
            xml_nodes("p") %>%
            html_text() %>%
            trimws() %>%
            enframe("paragraph_no", "text"),
        score = html %>%
            xml_nodes("[class='score']") %>%
            html_text() %>%
            as.numeric())
}
```

### Test 1:

[Grimes - Miss Anthropocene](https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene/)

```
get_pitchfork_data("http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene")
#$review
## A tibble: 14 x 2
#   paragraph_no text
#          <int> <chr>
# 1            1 Best new music
# 2            2 Grimes’ first project as a bona fide pop star is more morose th…
# 3            3 In 2011, Grimes was eager to say in an interview that she had “…
# 4            4 Miss Anthropocene is Grimes’ fifth album and her first as that …
# 5            5 The result is a record that’s more morose than her previous wor…
# 6            6 In November 2018, Grimes released “We Appreciate Power,” a coll…
# 7            7 When Grimes veers away from high concept toward examining intim…
# 8            8 Miss Anthropocene thrills when it reveals a refined, linear evo…
# 9            9 So much about the actual music of Miss Anthropocene succeeds th…
#10           10 And that’s the obstacle, the slimy mouthfeel, standing in the w…
#11           11 Correction: An earlier version of this review erroneously state…
#12           12 Listen to our Best New Music playlist on Spotify and Apple Musi…
#13           13 Buy: Rough Trade
#14           14 (Pitchfork may earn a commission from purchases made through af…
#
#$score
#[1] 8.2
```

### Test 2:

[Radiohead - OK Computer (reissue)](https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/radiohead-ok-computer-oknotok-1997-2017/)

```
get_pitchfork_data("https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/radiohead-ok-computer-oknotok-1997-2017/")
#$review
## A tibble: 12 x 2
#   paragraph_no text
#          <int> <chr>
# 1            1 Best new reissue
# 2            2 Twenty years on, Radiohead revisit their 1997 masterpiece with …
# 3            3 As they regrouped to figure out what their third album might be…
# 4            4 It’s still funny to think, two decades later, that Thom Yorke’s…
# 5            5 It’s unclear what happened to that album. OK Computer obviously…
# 6            6 OKNOTOK is something a little more interesting than a remaster …
# 7            7 But “Lift’s” reputation for positivity might be a little confus…
# 8            8 The most fun to be had with OKNOTOK is in these line-blurring m…
# 9            9 This fondness for camp and schlock has always been latent in Ra…
#10           10 The ghost of Bond followed them once they decamped from their s…
#11           11 Radiohead have been at least as brilliant at packaging and posi…
#12           12 Now that they have arrived at an autumnal, valedictory stage in…
#
#$score
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way to delete everything and leave just the the text of the review?

Comment: @warmsoda What do mean by "delete everything"? `get_pitchfork_data` only returns the review and the score. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I meant delete `## A tibble: 12 x 2
#   paragraph_no text
#          <int> <chr>`
and the number column. Is it possible to make it display the whole review?

Comment: @warmsoda I really don't understand what you mean; those are just the specs and column names of the `tibble`. The data is all there; it's just a matter of printing the contents of the `tibble` on screen. Do you understand the difference between how an R object is printed and what the R object contains?

Comment: @warmsodo If you only want the review as a a `character` vector you can do `get_pitchfork_data("http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene")$review$text`. Every entry in the vector corresponds to a text paragraph. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused since all this stuff is new to me. `$review$text` is what I wanted. However there are some white spaces and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @warmsoda Regarding whitespaces: you can use `trimws` to trim any leading/trailing whitespaces; try something like `trimws(get_pitchfork_data("http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene")$review$text)`; or probably better: modify the function and trim whitespaces when parsing the review.

Comment: Everything is so extremely helpful, thank you so much for your time and your help.

Comment: Is it possible for me to combine and print the text as 1 block instead of several blocks?

Comment: You're very welcome @warmsoda; sometimes I forget that beginning to code in R can be very puzzling and frustrating. I've made an edit to integrate `trimws` into the function. To concatenate the paragraphs you could play around with `paste`. For example try `res <- get_pitchfork_data("http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/grimes-miss-anthropocene"); review <- paste(res$review$text, collapse = "\n")`; `review` then contains all paragraphs concatenated with newline characters `"\n"`. The result is a `character` scalar.

Comment: Yea, I've started learning R for 2 months now and everything is still so confusing. You've been very kind and helpful, thank you.